# Do languages like JS with a copying GC ever store anything on the cpu registers?

Tags: javascript, c++, object, garbage-collection, v8

I am learning about GC's and I know there's a thing called `HandleScope` which 'protects' your local variables from the GC and updates them if a gc heap copy happens. For example, if I have a routine which adds togother 2 values and I call it, it may invoke the garbage collector which will copy the Object that my value is pointing to (or the GC will not even know that the Object the value is pointing to is referenced). A really minimal example:

```cpp
#include <vector>

Value addValues(Value a, Value b);
std::vector<Value*> gc_vals_with_protection;

Value func(Value a, Value b)
{
    vars.push_back(&a); // set protection for a
    gc_vals_with_protection.push_back(&b); // set protection for b
    Value res = addValues(a, b); // do calcuations
    gc_vals_with_protection.pop_back(); // remove protection for b
    gc_vals_with_protection.pop_back(); // remove protection for a
    return res;
}
```

But this has got me thinking, it will mean that `a` and `b` will NEVER be on the physical CPU registers because you have taken their addresses (and CPU registers don't have addresses) which will make calcuations on them inefficient. Also, at the beggining of every function, you would have to push back twice to the vector (https://godbolt.org/z/dc6vY1Yc5 for assembly).

I think I may be missing something, as this must be not optimal. Is there any other trick I am missing?

Comment: Accessing memory from the l1 cache is generally as fast as from registers. I don't have any insight into the js interpreter, but my guess would be there's potential for local primitive values to be written into registers (also I can guarantee that the allocation strategy for refernce counting won't be as naiive as your assumed example).

Comment: @George yeah but the operations are done on the registers themselves, so reading / writing back to l1 cache will eventually hurt performance. even the function local protection setup part is such a monstorous function (like 20 instructions alone for that).

Comment: In modern JavaScript runtimes code is basically translated to native machine instructions. With most modern CPUs, it's not possible to avoid using registers for evaluating expressions anyway. Also, JavaScript is single-threaded; GC doesn't happen while a thread is running in response to an event. (I should have said "some code"; it's not all JIT-translated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

> Do languages like JS with a copying GC ever store anything on the cpu registers?

Yes, of course. Pretty much anything at all that a CPU does involves its registers.

That said, JavaScript objects are generally allocated on the heap anyway, for at least the following reasons:
(1) They are bigger than a register. So registers typically hold pointers to objects on the heap. It's these pointers, not the objects themselves, that Handles are needed for (both to update them, and to inform the GC that there are references to the object in question, so the object must not be freed).
(2) They tend to be much longer-lived than the typical amount of time you can hold something in a register, which is only a couple of machine instructions: since the set of registers is so small, they are reused for something else *all the time* (regardless of JavaScript or GC etc), so whatever they held before will either be spilled (usually though not necessarily to the stack), or re-read from wherever it originally came from next time it's needed.
(3) They have "pointer identity": JavaScript code like `obj1 === obj2` (for objects, not primitives) only works correctly when there is exactly one location where an object is stored. Trying to store objects in registers would imply copying them around, which would break this.

There is certainly some cost to creating Handles; it's faster than adding something to a `std::vector` though.
Also, when passing Handles from one function to another, the called function doesn't have to re-register anything: Handles can be passed around without having to create new entries in the HandleScope's backing store.

A very important observation is that JavaScript functions don't need Handles for their locals. When executing JavaScript, V8 carefully keeps track of the contents of the stack (i.e. spilled contents of registers), and can walk and update the stack directly. HandleScopes are only needed for C++ code dealing with JS objects, because this technique isn't possible for C++ stack frames (which are controlled by the C++ compiler). Such C++ code is typically not the most critical performance bottleneck of an app; so while its performance certainly *matters*, some amount of overhead is acceptable.
(Side note: one can "blindly" (i.e. without knowledge about their contents) scan C++ stack frames and do so-called "conservative" (instead of "precise") garbage collection; this comes with its own pros and cons, in particular it makes a moving GC impossible, so is not directly relevant to your question.)

Taking this one step further: sufficiently "hot" functions will get compiled to optimized machine code; this code is the result of careful analysis and hence can be quite aggressive about keeping *values* (primarily numbers) in registers as long as possible, for example for chains of calculations before the final result is eventually stored in some property of some object.

For completeness, I'll also mention that *sometimes*, entire objects can be held in registers: this is when the optimizing compiler successfully performs "escape analysis" and can prove that the object never "escapes" to the outside world. A simple example would be:

```
function silly(a, b) {
  let vector = {x: a, y: b};
  return vector.x + vector.y;
}
```

When this function gets optimized, the compiler can prove that `vector` never escapes, so it can skip the allocation and keep `a` and `b` in registers (or at least as "standalone values", they might still get spilled to the stack if the function is bigger and needs those registers for something else).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think there was a misunderstanding, I meant, doesn't never storing pointers to objects hurt performance? Because then you would have to do a double load instead of 1.

Comment: Sure, using Handles has a performance cost. But (as I tried to explain) in the grand scheme of things, that cost is paid infrequently enough to not be a big problem. Another mitigating factor: C++ code that's carefully crafted not to allocate also doesn't need to be GC-safe, so doesn't need Handles. We use that for various performance-critical functions. So we're _not never_ using raw pointers, far from it: looking at the big picture, Handles are rare, raw pointers are frequent.

Comment: I understand. Thanks and have a good day

Comment: One more thing I forgot to point out: having a GC at all is dictated by the language, having a _moving_ GC or not is an implementation choice of the engine. It's totally possible to build a JavaScript engine with a GC that doesn't copy/move objects. The tradeoff is that in that case you can't do compaction of memory pages.

Comment: Yeah of course. No idea why I said 'JS' and not 'V8'. I have an off topic question: I want to create my own language (like js, with gc) and I understand how most gc's work but I don't know which to do on my own. I think the naive mark & sweep stop the world would perform bad (as I heard) but I also thinking not having addresses stability (copying gc) would be too much for a begginer like me. Would you please mind pointing me to somewhere? I just want preferably no memory overhead per object and good allocation performance. Thanks

Comment: For a single-person project I'd probably prioritize simplicity above all else, but that's just my opinion and opinion-based questions are indeed off-topic here.